# Deploy WAR file to WAS. worklight.properties

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Version: Worklight 6.0

I'm following the instructions in infocenter for deploying the war file to a standalone websphere application server 8.5 and there is one step that I do not understand.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_ant_tasks_sample_config_files.html

*Step 5.
In the configureapplicationserver and unconfigureapplicationserver invocations (in target install and uninstall), define Worklight properties. For a list of properties that can be set, see Configuration of IBM Worklight applications on the server. In production, you must often define the following specific properties:
    publicWorkLightHostname
    publicWorkLightProtocol
    publicWorkLightPort*

In configureapplicationserver/unconfigureapplicationserver those properties do not exist, how do I define them and where and how do I use them in the ant file?

Or does this mean that before using this ant script I have to change the values of those properties in the worklight.properties file and (automatically) generate the WAR file? If this is the case I think it is not clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the three properties in install/uninstall target like this:

```
<property name="publicWorkLightHostname" value="myhost.com"/>
<property name="publicWorkLightProtocol" value="http"/>
<property name="publicWorkLightPort" value="9080"/>
```

Or you can set the three properties in worklight.properties file before running Ant. To set the properties, open the war file with tools like 7zip and modify the worklight.properties.